# List doesn't get updated on click, only when the page is refreshed

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I have this simple app based on JSON local data. Basically a product list and and a category. The goal is to filter products per category, and somewnat I've managed todo it so, but something is weird and wrong because the product list dosnt'te get updated on click in the category list, but is I refresh the page and leave the filter as I wanted, the products ara updated, corresponding to the filter. I dont know hat is causing this and after inumeous arrenots I ended up here asking the community... The code:

The service providing json data:

```js
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private htttp: HttpClient) {}

  getAllProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.htttp.get<Product[]>("assets/products.json").pipe(
      map((p) => {
        let result = p[0]["products"];
        return result;
      })
    );
  }
  getCategories(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.htttp.get<any[]>("assets/categories.json").pipe(
      map((p) => {
        let result = p[0]["categories"];
        return result;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The basw component that holdsand handles all the logic:

```js
export class BaseShopComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: any[];
  products: Product[];
  category: string;
  filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.category = params["categories"];
      console.log(this.category);
    });

    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
      this.products = data;
      this.filteredProducts = this.category
        ? this.products.filter(
            (p) => p.category.toLowerCase() === this.category.toLowerCase()
          )
        : this.products;
    });

    this.getCategories();
  }

  getCategories() {
    this.productService.getCategories().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.categories = data;
    });
  }
}
```

The way data is passed to other components:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-left-shop></app-left-shop>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <app-content-shop
        [products]="products"
        [filteredProducts]="filteredProducts"
      ></app-content-shop>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-right-shop
        [categories]="categories"
        [category]="category"
      ></app-right-shop>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the receivers/redenders TS

```
export class RightShopComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() categories: any[];
@Input() category:string;
```

And HtML

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item"  
    *ngFor="let c of categories"
    [class.active]="c.name===category"
    routerLink="/shop"
    [queryParams]="{categories:c.name}">
        {{c.name}}
    </a>
</ul>
```

TS

```js
export class ContentShopComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() products: Product[];
  @Input() filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
}
```

nd finally, the Html:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let p of filteredProducts">
    {{p.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Im lost, I admit. I cant figure out the reason for this bad behaviour. Someone can help»

Comment: Can you reproduce this in stackblitz.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BaseShopComponent your'e fetching queryParams and the category list. Also to filter the products based on the category you need to call the product fetch method whenever the queryParams changes. currently your'e doing in `onInit` it will execute only once.

write fetchProducts as separate function and call whenever the queryParams changes

```
  onInit(){
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
       if(params.categories){
         this.category = params["categories"];
         this.fetchProducts();               <== Refresh When Category Changes 
         console.log(this.category);
       }
     });
     this.fetchProducts();  <== Initial Call
     this.getCategories();
   }


    fetchProducts() {
       this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
        this.products = data;
        this.filteredProducts = this.category
          ? data.filter(
            (p) => p.category.toLowerCase() === this.category.toLowerCase()
           )
         : data;
      });
    }
```

Comment: that did the trick, thank you. I was in the wrong path because I m using the same logic that came from in a component communication architecture completely different. Changing it made me learn more a bit about component communication tahks :)

Comment: @Mellville Happy Coding :)